# Set up an integral that is obtained by rotating the given curve about the $x$ axis and find the surface area

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, parametric

> Set up an integral that is obtained by rotating the given curve about the $x$ axis and find the surface area.

$$
\begin{aligned}
x &= t\sin(t) & y &= t\cos(t) & 0 &\leq t \leq \frac{\pi}{2}
\end{aligned}
\\
\int_{0}^{\pi/2} 2 \pi t\cos\left(t\right) \sqrt{\left(\sin\left(t\right)+t\cos\left(t\right)\right)^2+\left(\cos(t)-t\sin\left(t\right)\right)^2}\;dt
$$

Is my integral set up correctly and from what I see it looks like integration by parts inside of integration by parts with u- substitution, and there is no way, unless I use some identities or tricks. How do I simplify this?

Comment: You set it up correctly (aside from the dt missing at the end of the integral), but you still need to simplify the expression under the square root, of course.  (The resulting integral can be approximated numerically.)